# UWP Pivot: No blue underline on focused pivot item

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Does anyone have an idea why the blue underline on a focused pivot item is not visible? The xaml (in a newly created empty UWP app with .NET core 2.0, VS 2017 15.3.2) is simple like that:

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem Header="Testt 1">Test 1</PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Testt 2">Test 2</PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Testt 3">Test 3</PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

and MS is saying that "By default, keyboard focus on a pivot header is represented with an underline." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tabs-pivot)

Very few times after startup, it was there on the first pivot item but disappeared after clicking on another one.

Comment: "Very few times after startup, it was there on the first pivot item but disappeared after clicking on another one." What if you tab between them instead of clicking? It does say keyboard focus after all. I'd also be surprised if it was there after startup without you having done anything yet.

Comment: Ahhh, you are right, then it appears! How can I make it show up on clicking/tapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the style of `PivotHeaderItem`, there is a `Rectangle` called `FocusPipe` which is the focus visual that you see during keyboard navigation. By default, it's only visible when it's in the `Focused` state.

If you want to make it visible, simply set its `Visibility` to `Visible` in `Selected`, `SelectedPressed` and `SelectedPointerOver` states.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
        <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing"
                Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemBackgroundUnselected}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemForegroundUnselected}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="48" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Unselected"
                                                      To="UnselectedLocked"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                    <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked"
                                                      To="Unselected"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                                         Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                         Duration="0"
                                                         To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="FocusPipe.Visibility"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemBackgroundSelected}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemForegroundUnselectedPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemBackgroundUnselectedPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="FocusPipe.Visibility"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemForegroundUnselectedPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemBackgroundUnselectedPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="FocusPipe.Visibility"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="FocusPipe.Visibility"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                          FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                          FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusPipe"
                                   Fill="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFocusPipeFill}"
                                   Height="2"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

a simpler answer is:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderItemSelectedPipeFill" Color="Yellow"/>
```

for a yellow underline.

Comment: i did not see the solidcolorbrush: x:key PivotHeaderItemSelectedPipeFill

Comment: Worked perfectly.